# How would I get this ViewController like my attached image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

[image]

I am using Objective-c.

In this picture, I have a UITabbar controller with five tab bar items, which is then embedded inside a navigation controller.

The red circled view controlled is the third tab bar item in my tab bar controller.

I want to get this specific, outlined view controller,because I have a delegate method to call back this view controller.

But, I don't know how to get this red outlined view controller.

Thanks.

I want to get the code like this:

```
 UINavigationController *navi =[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0 ];
 RedCicleViewController *redCicleViewController = [navi.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

        self.addDelegate = RedCicleViewController;
        [self.addDelegate UpdateCell:nil];
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: have u embedded UINavigation Controller for every items ?

Comment: Why index 0 in  [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0 ] , it should be 2?

Comment: 2 is null. so , I don't know how to get.